# Java keyword in front of new declaration

Tags: java

Im trying to learn some Java.

When i run the below code, it works:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test;

/**
 *
 * @author me
 */
public class Test {

    int myAge;

    public getAge( ){
        system.out.println(myAge);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Test Tester = new Test();
        Tester.myAge = 5;

        System.out.println(Tester.myAge);
    }

}
```

As you can see there is a Test Tester in my main function. When i remove it like so:

```
Tester = new Test();
```

It does not work anymore. Why should i add Test before this function.
Remember, I'm still very noob in Java programming (this is my first ever program) so be gentle.

Comment: You need to declare the type of Tester which is Test in this case. That's just a requirement of Java syntax.

Comment: `{Type} {variableName} = {expression};` is a declaration with an assignment. `{variableName} = {expression}` is 'just' an assignment and *the variable must already be declared* (or you will get the errors that you are getting). It is the `{Type}` clause that *makes* it a declaration and not an ordinary assignment.

Comment: Btw please follow the naming convention. Local variable names should be in camelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java works in the way that

```
TypeName var_name = new TypeConstructor();
```

Here, TypeName is your  class name. You can however, do it in two parts:

```
TypeName var_name; // IN the beginning


var_name = new TypeConstructor(); // Or using some other method that returns an object of TypeName
```

However, you need to make sure that it gets instantiated or assigned correctly. Without TypeName, Java cannot resolve the `new TypeConstructor()` syntax like the way you've done.

One key thing to remember is that `TypeName` and `TypeConstructor` must be of the same type with regards to `var_name`. You cannot do like the following

```
String var_name;  // I declared var_name of type String
var_name = new Tester(); // I instantiate var_name to have defaults of type Tester - fails
```

"Instantiation" and "declaration" are keys here - You can simply leave an "Uninstantiated" variable `var_name` and Java wouldn't scream. See the example on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/UcJJ6v). It's like a job contract that you sign with your employer (t&c applies). Once you sign it (declare Test to be of type `Tester`), you cannot simply go back and say that "I will be making "Test"s of type Tester" (i.e. Test = new Tester()). You are breaking the t&c of contract, unless you arrange a new contract.

Comment: Can i also do this than? `string Tester;` and later on `Tester = new Test();`?

Comment: No, because your declaration of `Tester` is of type `String`. You need to understand the basics of Java declaration and instantiation.

Comment: What "type" is Test than? because Test is not a type imo, but it's my class... Sorry for being noob xD

Comment: `Tester` is your variable (or object). You should've named it in Java camelCase. `Test` is the class name. You used default constructor for your `Test`class. You need to read about Java and how to create an object of a class (i.e. how to instantiate a class properly). See @NeerajJain below where he posted a good link on this.

Comment: It's kind of the same as PHP I notice now. Only a slight difference in syntax. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: I'm following http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm is this any good?

Comment: @Dennis         DOn't get confused with php, javascript and java. PHP, Javascript are dynamically typed where Java is strongly typed language with the emphasis on Object-Orientation. Scripting language is a subset of High-Level languages e.g. Java/C/C++.

Comment: Yea i know ;) But i think that Classes in PHP look like the classes in Java so far. I just began to learn Java so maybe that will change also.

Answer (score 7):

You need to tell the compiler what *type* `Tester` is.

You might think the compiler could work this out given you're creating a `Test()`, but it can't. This is because `Tester` can be many things; typically an *interface* that `Test()` implements, or a *base class*.

E.g. you could also have written `java.lang.Object Tester = new Test()`.

Comment: what does java.lang.Object do?

Comment: It's the base class of *every* class in Java.

Answer (score 4):

`Test tester = new Test()` can be broken down like so:

1. `Test` declares a variable of object type `Test` with name....
2. `tester`
3. `=` assigns this created reference to what evaluated on the right hand side
4. `new` creates a new object on the heap of type...
5. `Test()` an empty-constructor initializing the instance created by `new`

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new object in java you have 4 Keywords which are required.  The Type(Class) of the object, the variable name `= new` constructor call`()`.  Unless you have made a previous declaration such as this : `Test Tester;` you cannot simply type `Tester = new Test()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent tutorial about [How to Create Objects in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

`Tester` is a reference variable of class `Test` which compiler does not able to know untill you specify in a way which Java Suggest

```
ClassName referenceVariablName=new ClassName(); //You can also pass arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is not dynamic typing language like Ruby or JavaScript. It is static typing language. So, for compiler you need to define type for all variables.